# value should not repeat in database while inserting from foreach loop in c#

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

i m creating billing application and insert data from datagridview to database using foreach loop

this is my code ;

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow di in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
     con.Open();
     cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into bill_history values('" + txtctname.Text + "','" + txtadd.Text + "','" + label1.Text + "','" + label2.Text + "','" + di.Cells[0].Value + "','" + di.Cells[1].Value + "','" + di.Cells[3].Value + "','" + txtsub.Text + "','" + txttx.Text + "','" + txttotal.Text + "','" + txtdic.Text + "','" + txtgdt.Text + "','" + di.Cells[2].Value + "')", con);
     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

my result is:

```
    invoice no     prductname   price/piece   total
        1           ede              10         80
        1          santoor soap      20         80
        1              ewe           50         80
```

but i want this result invoice and total should not repeat plz help

```
    invoice no     prductname   price/piece   total
        1           ede              10         
                   santoor soap      20         
                       ewe           50         80
```

Comment: Be clear while you ask questions.If your invoice number is a primary key for the table it should not allow repeated values.Instead of handling this via c# code normalize your table properly.

Comment: Show us your code so we can help you

Comment: there is nothing primary key bcoz i m generating serial no from coading for invoice no .

Comment: That is no reason to not set it as a primary key in your database. Your concern seems to be not having the same invoice number twice, that is one of the things a PK takes care of. Next to that: never insert arguments straight from text boxes, it allows users to do all sorts of harm to your database.

Comment: i tried with PK but when run the loop and item is more than one that time its show error

Comment: As is should, you waned the invoice number to be unique so the database forbids you to add the same invoice twice (might be nice to try catch the call tough and tell the user there was a problem instead of a error).

Comment: Auto incrementing identity column that is also the Primary Key.

Answer (score 0):

What you really want to do is to learn it the right way. Your code example raises several red flags to an experienced programmer.

[Learn how to normalize your Database and what relations are](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hADxc8p42dI)

[image]

Also, you are trying to access your Database through ADO.Net. If you are going to use this, then [please do it the right way](http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorial/AdoDotNet) using Paramaters in your SqlCommand object.

Better yet, have a [look into Entity Framework](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/), an easy way to access your Database as objects in the code. This eliminates Sql queries from your code alltogether.